# Capture Output to stream and store as a string variable

Tags: string, perl, stream, bioperl

Although this question relates to 'BioPerl', the question, I believe, is probably more general than that.

Basically I have produced a [Bio::Tree::TreeI](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.923/Bio/Tree/TreeI.pm) object and I am trying to convert that into a string variable.

The only way I can come close to converting that to a string variable is to write that tree to a stream using:

```
# a $tree = Bio::Tree::TreeI->new() (which I know is an actual tree as it prints to the terminal console)

my $treeOut = Bio::TreeIO->new(-format => 'newick')
$treeOut->write_tree($tree)
```

The output of ->write_tree is "Writes a tree onto the stream" but how do I capture that in a string variable as I can't find another way of returning a string from any of the functions in [Bio::TreeIO](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/TreeIO.pm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way to accomplish the same goal by setting the file handle for BioPerl objects, and I think it is less of a hack. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::TreeIO;

my $treeio  = Bio::TreeIO->new(-format => 'newick', -fh => \*DATA);
my $treeout = Bio::TreeIO->new(-format => 'newick', -fh => \*STDOUT);

while (my $tree = $treeio->next_tree) {
    $treeout->write_tree($tree);
}

__DATA__
(A:9.70,(B:8.234,(C:7.932,(D:6.321,((E:2.342,F:2.321):4.231,((((G:4.561,H:3.721):3.9623,
I:3.645):2.341,J:4.893):4.671)):0.234):0.567):0.673):0.456);
```

Running this script prints the newick string to your terminal, as you would expect. If you use [Bio::Phylo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio%3a%3aPhylo) (which I recommend), there is a `to_string` method (IIRC), so you don't have to create an object just to print your trees, you can just do `say $tree->to_string`.

Comment: Ahh that's much more specific to the problem at hand. thanks for the info on Bio::Phylo

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect standard output to variable,

```
my $captured;
{
  local *STDOUT = do { open my $fh, ">", \$captured; $fh };
  $treeOut->write_tree($tree);
}
print $captured;
```